# Bot doesn't assign role in reaction role command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I've been trying to follow a tutorial on how to set up a reaction role command. Even though I do get the embed with the reactions that I wanted, when I react to it the bot doesn't assign the roles. After comparing the code to the tutorial I'm still not sure on what the problem here is.

This is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){
        const channel = '851809318843187262';
        const yellowTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "2D simp");
        const blueTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "3D simp");
 
        const yellowTeamEmoji = '<:wings:851814106146144326>';
        const blueTeamEmoji = '<:crowshine:851814012290203680>';
 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Choose a team to play on!')
            .setDescription('Choosing a team will allow you to interact with your teammates!\n\n'
                + `${yellowTeamEmoji} for yellow team\n`
                + `${blueTeamEmoji} for blue team`);
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(yellowTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(blueTeamEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(blueTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === blueTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(blueTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Anything else strange happening?

Comment: No, I get no error at all when I select a reaction. It all works until the part where I select it and there's nothing else to note other than that I don't get any role.

Comment: I believe that instead of putting client.on(...) there, you have to create a message collector.